# Is middleware in Laravel 5.7 necessary in routes only?

Tags: laravel

My question is in regards to a website that would have multiple user authorizations, vendor, customer, guest, admin, etc.

Each has their own controllers and middleware.

My question is a bit in confusion on when to use middleware. Would I be wrong to assume using middleware in my routes file only would be sufficient? It seems redundant unless I'm missing something in terms of the scoping ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 primary places you could use your middleware, in the `routes/*.php` files or directly in the controller.

Anecdotally I only use middleware in my routes files.

There is no difference in the effect of using middleware from routes or from controllers, in short, it is perfectly fine to use middleware only in your routes files.

Comment: Thank you. I suspected it could be used flexibly like that. Thank you for clearing up my concern.